# Difference between total order and linear order

Tags: notation, relations, order-theory, lattice-orders

I want to ask a clarificatory doubt. I am really confused with the two definitions of linear order. In one definition it is said to be same as total order but in the other definition it is irreflexive part of total order (which also named as strict total order).

So my question is whether by definition linear order is reflexive (in that case is equivalent to total order) Or irreflexive (in this case it is not equal to total order).

To put it differently which one is a linear order (i) Less than and equal to, or (ii) less than.

Thank you.

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) may help you.

Comment: Dear user0102, 

Thank you for your reply. But as I have mentioned that there are two different definitions of linear order. In the definition you have referred on Wikipedia, says that linear order is reflexive. But there are other sources which says it is the irreflexive part of total order.
I am giving the link of one such website:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+order 

So could you please clarify which one is correct or more acceptable definition of linear order. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Linear order or total order are the same thing.
The difference between being reflexive or irreflexive depends just on a detail about how you want to think about order relations (whether total or not).
In the case of irreflexive orders (either partial or total), these are called strict, as you can see in the linked page on a comment above.

You shouldn't worry too much about this, since these are always interchangeable:
if $\leq$ is a (reflexive) partial order on a set $X$, you can obtain its strict (irreflexive) version $<$ by defining $x<y$ iff $x \leq y$ and $x \neq y$;
conversely, if $<$ is a strict partial order (irreflexive), you can obtain the corresponding reflexive version by defining $x \leq y$ iff $x<y$ or $x=y$.

These procedures are mutual inverses, meaning that if you start with one version of the order and apply both (each one once), you end up with the same order you started with (this is rather trivial to observe).
Notice that all this is valid for any partial order, whence, in particular, for a total order.

If some author has a different definition for total order and linear order, that can be OK, but I never saw that distinction.
One definition (reflexive or irreflexive) is not more correct than the other; it just happens that there are authors which prefer one over the other, and sometimes there are areas in which one is more widely used.

Comment: Dear amrsa, thank you for your detailed reply. I totally get your point and these two are merely different definitions. Let me clarify the context of my doubt. I am writing a research paper where I want to write that a preference ordering P, is a linear order over a set of alternatives A. Then I want to define a set (B) of alternatives that are better than a i.e. $B=\{b \in A : b P a\}$. Now my question is whether a belongs to B or not. We know that it depends on whether P is reflexive or not. So which one is "more" common or acceptable definition of linear order.

Comment: @SarveshBandhu You are right that the difference between strict order or not determines whether or not $a \in B$. It's up to you (or the context of your research) to determine which one to use. Always bear in mind that you can shift between the two by the process described in the answer, if it becomes convenient. To make things clear, it is customary to denote by $\leq$ the reflexive orders and $<$ the strict (irreflexive ones), whether you need to work with both or not.

Comment: @SarveshBandhu You might as well take a tour through the [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) (there's a link a the bottom of the page), and there check the article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). That is, you if are satisfied with an answer, perhaps you'd like to accept it as the right answer (often people let 24 hours pass since the posting of the question to allow more users to get a chance of answering; I suppose that doesn't apply when one is sure there'a already a good enough answer).